# Is it possible to update a user's facebook status without having them install an application?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

My intention is to have a user initiate a status update from a webpage by clicking a link or button. 
I would most likely be using a combination of php and javascript to do this. I was hoping to update the status without the user needing to install an application. Is it possible?

Comment: I sure hope this is not possible.

Comment: The user would still need to be authenticated. I just don't want them to have to install "another" app.

Comment: Ok, I've seen links after you 'like' a company or product that let you update your status, and I don't think they require an application.

Comment: Some links are actually superimposed on a trigger for some Javascript, which then posts on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The user will need to give your app permission to do so. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ on how to give them a dialog box to update their feed.

Comment: So the user grants permission each time the app is used, but doesn't require the user to install it? IF that's right then this may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: No installation required. The examples should work out of the box, so give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. it is possible by using Graph API,
first you need to get OAuth key that is it. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

you can get access token from above link. as well as you can check.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do without authentication of some kind. Here is Facebook's API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: I have no problem with the user authenticating. I just want to avoid having them install an app everytime they want to update their status from a different website.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to install app. Also no need of authenticate the app every time. Once App was authenticated by user after that no need to authenticate next time.